# Removing alert when writing correct password using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had 2 fields old password and new password.In that old password field I am giving the old password that was already saved in the database.If its not correct its giving an alert message but that alert was not removing after giving the correct password. I had given this inside the blur function

Comment: share some code.

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the necessary codes. But the general way to do that is as follows:

```js
var oldpass = '1234',
    old = document.getElementById( 'oldPass' );

  old.addEventListener( 'blur', function () {
    if ( this.value && this.value != oldpass ) { 
      alert( 'Password don\'t Match!' )
    } else {
      document.getElementById( 'newPass' ).removeAttribute( 'disabled' );
      document.getElementById( 'newPass' ).focus()
    }
  } )
```

```html
<p>Old Password is: <b>1234</b></p>
<input type="text" id="oldPass" placeholder="Enter old password" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="newPass" placeholder="Enter a new password" disabled />
```

Or you can do that when user is typing the password:

```js
var oldpass = '1234',
    old = document.getElementById( 'oldPass' );

  old.addEventListener( 'input', function () {
    if ( this.value != oldpass ) { 
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    } else {
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      document.getElementById( 'newPass' ).removeAttribute( 'disabled' );
      document.getElementById( 'newPass' ).focus()
    }
  } )
```

```html
<p>Old Password is: <b>1234</b></p>
<input type="text" id="oldPass" placeholder="Enter old password" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="newPass" placeholder="Enter a new password" disabled />
```